# Need to show custom popup on navigate away from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checkout page. I want to show custom popup using HTML/CSS when user navigate  away from browser before checkout completed. Like  refresh the browser, close the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use unload function if you are using jquery

```
$(document).unload(function(){
    showPopup() - show your popup here
});
```

if you want to pause the borwser while exiting tab you need to use confirm console in javascript

```
confirm('Are you going to leave')
```

I think that would work for you

if you are using pure javascript there is function `onunload()` for that

Comment: Not working. I am getting console error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unload is not a function